# What does @ mean in -rw-r--r--@?

Tags: mac-osx

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 abc  staff  1088808  8 31 09:55 marcus_gow
```

Anyone knows this, what's it for?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: The "staff" group makes it look like OSX to me.

Comment: I'd think the same thing, but he tagged it [tag:linux] when it's almost certainly not Linux.

Comment: As @abc already seems to got some proper answers, here's my Friday reply: obviously it's "wall rodent worm wall rodent wall wall rodent wall wall Nethack_hero"

Comment: See [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/53277/387) question as well.

Answer (score 32):

[**`man ls`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/ls.1.html)

> If the file or directory has extended attributes, the permissions
>   field printed by the `-l` option is followed by a '@' character.

```
ls -l@ /path/to/marcus_gow
xattr -l /path/to/marcus_gow
```

Answer (score 12):

It means that the files has [extended attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes).